# Using public key coordinate with Crypto++'s ECDH class

Tags: c++, crypto++, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I'm using crypto++ for ECDH key agreement

```
ECDH.Agree(key, privateKey, outherpublicKey);
```

Given that for public key I have only X and Y coordinates. How to generate publicKey from this values ?

```
ECDH.Agree(key,privateKey, getPublicKey(X,Y))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Given that for public key I have only X and Y coordinates..."* - Forgive my ignorance (and so I am clear...), which public key is it? Is it the temporary, ephemeral key used for the ECDH protocol, or is it a long term, static key?

Comment: ephemeral one, at each key establishment, i send X,Y coordinate to  this function to generate a new session key

Comment: If you can show me how to produce X,Y from a public key and how to use them(my main objective), it will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given that for public key I have only X and Y coordinates. How to generate publicKey from this values?
>   `ECDH.Agree(key,privateKey, getPublicKey(X,Y))`

`{x,y}` is a point on the curve, but its never been easy to work with it directly.

This is all we really want to do but it does not work. The problem is `ECDH::Domain` are only domain parameters. The public point and the private exponent are layered on top.

```
OID curve = ASN1::secp256r1();
DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP> params(curve);

Integer x("...");
Integer y("...");
ECP::Point q(x, y);

DL_PublicKey_EC<ECP> pubKey;
pubKey.Initialize(params, q);

ECDH < ECP >::Domain theirs(pubKey);
```

To further complicate matters, the keys produced by the ECDH protocol are temporary or ephemeral. They are not meant to be persisted; rather, they are meant to be used once and discarded. So Crypto++ does not make it easy to persist them (by, say, providing a `DEREncode`).

***Analysis***

To use the `{x,y}` coordinate, we need to figure out how the library is using it. The ephemeral public and private keys are created in [`pubkey.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/pubkey_8h_source.html#l01380) around line 1380. The code for them is below:

```
void GeneratePrivateKey(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, byte *privateKey)
{
    Integer x(rng, Integer::One(), GetAbstractGroupParameters().GetMaxExponent());
    x.Encode(privateKey, PrivateKeyLength());
}

void GeneratePublicKey(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const byte *privateKey, byte *publicKey)
{
    const DL_GroupParameters<T> &params = GetAbstractGroupParameters();
    Integer x(privateKey, PrivateKeyLength());
    Element y = params.ExponentiateBase(x);
    params.EncodeElement(true, y, publicKey);
}
```

The line of interest above is the `params.EncodeElement(true, y, publicKey)`. To see what's going on there, we need to look at [`eccrypto.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/eccrypto_8h_source.html#l00061) around line 70, and note that `reversible` is `true`:

```
void EncodeElement(bool reversible, const Element &element, byte *encoded)
{
    if (reversible)
        GetCurve().EncodePoint(encoded, element, m_compress);
    else
        element.x.Encode(encoded, GetEncodedElementSize(false));
}
```

`params.EncodeElement` calls `ECP::EncodePoint`. To see what that does we can examine [`ecp.cpp`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/ecp_8cpp_source.html#l00118) around line 120. The routine writes a uncompressed point, but blocks `x` and `y` on the maximum size of the public element, which should be the field size or the subgroup order.

```
void ECP::EncodePoint(BufferedTransformation &bt, const Point &P, bool compressed)
{
    if (P.identity)
        NullStore().TransferTo(bt, EncodedPointSize(compressed));
    else if (compressed)
    {
        bt.Put(2 + P.y.GetBit(0));
        P.x.Encode(bt, GetField().MaxElementByteLength());
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int len = GetField().MaxElementByteLength();
        bt.Put(4);      // uncompressed
        P.x.Encode(bt, len);
        P.y.Encode(bt, len);
    }
}
```

Don't worry too much about the `BufferedTransformation`. There are ways to turn a `byte[]` into one, and it happened before the code shown above. If you trace the code, you will see its transformed via an `ArraySource`:

```
byte myArray[PublicEphemeralKeyLength()];
ArraySource as(myArray, COUNTOF(myArray));
```

Above, `as` is a `BufferedTransformation` that wraps the `byte[]` you passed into the function.

The final open question is the maximum size of the field element. That appears to be the modulus size less one, in bytes:

```
$ grep -I -A 1 MaxElementByteLength modarith.h 
    unsigned int MaxElementByteLength() const
        {return (m_modulus-1).ByteCount();}
```

***Agreement***

Given the above information, here's what you should do. You need to supply the values for `x` and `y` in `ECP::Point q(x,y)`. They are just Crypto++ Integers.

```
OID curve = ASN1::secp256r1();
DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP> params(curve);

size_t size = params.GetEncodedElementSize(true);
vector<byte> othersPublicKey(size);

ECP::Point q(x,y);
params.EncodeElement(true, q, &othersPublicKey[0]);
```

Then you can call:

```
ecdh.Agree(key, myPrivateKey, &othersPublicKey[0]);
```

One note: `params.GetEncodedElementSize(true)` should equal `PublicEphemeralKeyLength()`. If they are not equal, then something is wrong.

---

If you need to modify compression, then you can:

```
params.SetPointCompression(true);
```

---

I'll get this added to Crypto++'s [Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie-Hellman) wiki page so others don't have to go rummaging for it.

Comment: I take benefit from your knowledge and ask you, when I use GenerateKeyPair, how to get X,Y coordinates from generated public key?

Comment: @Singa - Ask a new question. I don't mind answering them, but we should keep the Questions/Answers targeted and focused.

Comment: @SingaCpp how to get X,Y coordinates from generated public key ? did you found solution for it